# Countdown reloads on refresh

Tags: html, css

Everytime I refresh page, countdown timer reloads. What I found is that I need to use local storage for that( I guess), but how Im I able to implement that in this javascript countdown code?
Here is my JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BrsJsk/srv3ywnL/

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 59 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
   <div id="clockdiv">
      <p1 class="dayss"><span class="num days">34</span> days</p1>
      <p1 class="hourss"><span class="num hours">16</span> hours</p1>
      <p1 class="secondss"><span class="num seconds">1</span> secs</p1>
      <p1 class="minutess"><span class="num minutes">19</span> mins</p1>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess you could use cookies...

Comment: @SankarshMakam localstorage is way easier than cookies. On `window.unload`, set a localstorage with the time currently remaining -
 `localStorage.setItem('clock', someVar)` then on page load, `if (localStorage.getItem('clock')) { var deadline = localStorage.getItem('clock'); } else { var deadline = new Date(); }`

Comment: Are you saying that you wish for the countdown to pause and then resume when the user is back? You'd need storage for that like you say. Else, if you want it to continue counting down even if the user has gone away for sometime and come back, you would need to begin your countdown to a fixed position in time.

Comment: I suggest doing some research into [the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)) and how it works. Try something, then let us know if you need help with a specific aspect of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain a static moment in time to count down *to*. Each time in your code you're getting the current date and so it resets on load.

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xrwm51sg/

**The key line, would be:**

```
var deadline = new Date("Oct 2, 2020 12:30:00").getTime();
```

Then you would minus this time by the current quantity of time now.

```
var t = endtime - new Date().getTime();
```

**Full working code:**

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {

  var t = endtime - new Date().getTime();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date("Oct 2, 2020 12:30:00").getTime();
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to count down to a specific time, you could take a look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using local storage,Here is your code with localstorage

```
<div id="clockdiv">
  <p1 class="dayss"><span class="num days">34</span> days</p1>
  <p1 class="hourss"><span class="num hours">16</span> hours</p1>
  <p1 class="secondss"><span class="num seconds">1</span> secs</p1>
  <p1 class="minutess"><span class="num minutes">19</span> mins</p1>
</div>
<script>

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    //var value = parseInt(endtime);
    localStorage.setItem("counter", endtime);
    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

  if(localStorage.getItem("counter")){
    var deadline = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    }else{
      var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 59 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }

initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abhaybhosale/3eg99sxa/1/